# CopySubresourceRegion incorrectly reports an error about the size of the source box?

Tags: directx-11

I have a source ID3D11Texture2D of size 2560x1440 (from a screenshot), a quarter of which (half width and height) I am copying into a staging ID3D11Texture2D surface created with a width of 1280 (=2560/2) and height of 720 (=1440/2) (as specified in D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC before calling ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D()).

Calling..

```
ID3D11DeviceContext::CopySubresourceRegion(dst=staging, 0, 0, 0, 0, src=screenshot, 0, box={0,0,0,1281,721,1});
```

.. works fine (the staging surface contains all the data I expect), but the D3D11 debug layer reports the following error:

```
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::CopySubresourceRegion: When offset by the destination coordinates, pSrcBox does not fit on the destination subresource.
OffsetSrcBox = { left:0, top:0, front:0, right:1281, bottom:721, back:1 }.
DstSubresource = { left:0, top:0, front:0, right:1280, bottom:720, back:1 }.
[ RESOURCE_MANIPULATION ERROR #280: COPYSUBRESOURCEREGION_INVALIDSOURCEBOX]
```

Since the *width* and *height* of the staging (destination) surface are 1280 and 720, it looks to me like it's CopySubresourceRegion which is incorrectly working out *DstSubresource* as {0,0,0,1280,720,1} - instead of {0,0,0,*1281*,*721*,1} as I'd expect it to be (*front* and *back* are correct) - and then cheekily reporting that to me as an error - when *it* made the mistake.

I *did* double-check that D3D11_BOX was correct (the doc says "*The values for right, bottom, and back are each one pixel past the end of the pixels that are included in the box region*").

I do not want to mess around with offsets or create a staging surface with the *wrong* width and height (1281x721) just to make this error disappear, so I am correct in that this error is misleading, or am I unknowingly doing something wrong? (I'm still quite new at coding for D3D11.)

Comment: D'oh! See my own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that I have been a bit stupid. The DstSubresource box (the destination in the staging surface) is indeed correct: it's 1280 pixels wide, so the pixels go from #0 to #1279 (and #1280 is the *one pixel past the end*).

Where I went wrong is in the specification of the source region, whose box I specified with:

```
left = 0;
top = 0;
right = width + 1;
bottom = height + 1;
```

As soon as I properly noticed that there was both "width" and "+1" together (same for the height), when it's always *width = (right-left)* of course and therefore wasn't the same, I realised my mistake.

So, it was nothing to do with being new at coding for D3D11, and everything to do with an inattention error.